# Как быстро удалить индексы в таблице MySQL?

Tags: индексы, mysql

Возможно ли быстро удалить мои 7 индексов из таблицы в MySQL? Как-то например в один запрос прописать удаление всех индексов?

Потому что в базе 400к записей и один индекс удаляется по 15 минут. Очень долго :(

Comment: можно так:

    create memory table tab_temp as select * from tab;
    truncate tab;
    alter table drop index....
    insert from select...

все зависит от физических размеров...  

или сразу в новую таблицу копировать данные. пробовать надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alter table `имя таблицы` drop index `имя 1 индекса`;
alter table `имя таблицы` drop index `имя 2 индекса`;
alter table `имя таблицы` drop index `имя 3 индекса`;
alter table `имя таблицы` drop index `имя 4 индекса`;
alter table `имя таблицы` drop index `имя 5 индекса`;
alter table `имя таблицы` drop index `имя 6 индекса`;
alter table `имя таблицы` drop index `имя 7 индекса`;
```

Иного способа избавиться от индекса нет, то есть одной пулей 7 зайцев вы убить не сможете.

Answer (score 2):

Серебряная пуля есть при использовании `information_schema`. Можно и одним запросом:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP INDEX first, DROP INDEX second, …;
```

На чистом SQL пока не хватило терпения сделать (ибо разбираться с курсором/циклами - сейчас не охота), но с приправой ЯП можно очень удобно организовать.

Вот таким образом можно получить названия индексов для база.таблица:

```
SET @dbName = 'dbName';
SET @tableName = 'tableName';
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME FROM `information_schema`.`STATISTICS` WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @dbName AND INDEX_NAME <> 'PRIMARY';
```

Поскольку без удаления атрибута AI PRIMARY индекс не сбросить, то:

> INDEX_NAME <> 'PRIMARY'

Далее - по циклу вставляем названия индексов и "роняем" их.

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON @dbName.@tableName;
```

Пример на PHP:

```
public function dropIndexes($tableName = 'table', $dbName = 'db')
{
    $db = $this->getAdapter();

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME as `index` FROM `information_schema`.`STATISTICS` WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$tableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName' AND INDEX_NAME <> 'PRIMARY';";

    $result = $db->fetchAll($query);

    foreach ($result as $index) {
        $query = "DROP INDEX `" . $index['index'] . "` ON `$dbName`.`$tableName`;";
        $db->query($query);
    }
}
```